# Coherence in sentence (2)

Tags: sentence-patterns

1. Does this sentence make sense:

"After all other people had already boarded the bus, the bus conductor came to the hotel cafeteria and warned us to hurry up, or we would have to get to the airport BY OUR OWN MEANS."

2. And in case the sentence before makes sense and is correct, what do you understand by "by our own means"?

Comment: https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/means

Comment: Do you mean the bus **driver**? A bus conductor is a person, not the driver, who rides on a bus to sell tickets.

Comment: The use of *already* is redundant and it could be removed. I'd also use *or **else** we would*.

Answer (score 1):

> "After all other people had already boarded the bus, the bus conductor
>   came to the hotel cafeteria and warned us to hurry up, or we would
>   have to get to the airport BY OUR OWN MEANS."

is correct, but

"After all other people had already boarded the bus, the bus conductor came to the hotel cafeteria and warned us to hurry up, or we would have to get to the airport ON OUR OWN."

would also sound good.

"BY OUR OWN MEANS" indicates that if you didn't hurry up, you would have to go to the airport using another method/way of transportation and not that particular bus. It basically means that you'd have to go to the airport "ON YOUR OWN" some way or the other.